# ontology versioning: Link both versionIRI#MyClassIRI and ontologyIRI#MyClass123 to same resource in rdf / owl

Tags: sparql, rdf, owl, ontology, w3c

## I want to use 2 synonymous IRIs to SPARQL query for same resource (from most recent ontology)

I want to be able to construct SPARQL queries for the latest version of my ontology (example.org/myontology/) I want each resource to be reachable in 2 synonymous ways:

- versionIRI#MyClassIRI, eg. example.org/myontology/v04/MyClass123
- ontologyIRI#MyClass123,  eg. example.org/myontology/MyClass123 (the "unversioned" version)

So

`SELECT * {example.org/myontology/**v04**/MyClass123 ?p ?o}`

and

`SELECT * {example.org/myontology/MyClass123 ?p ?o}`

yield the same result.

I am aware that I could use

`SELECT GRAPH /0.4 SELECT * {example.org/myontology/MyClass123 ?p ?o}` to reach the specific file, I do not want to do that.

## I want to be able to SPARQL query for retired ontologies' concepts

For retired versions, that for code stability reasons need to have unchanging unversioned IRI, I want the same class to only be reachable by the versionIRI, so:

- versionIRI#MyClassIRI, eg. example.org/myontology/**v03**/MyClass123

`SELECT * {example.org/myontology/**v03**/MyClass123 ?p ?o}`

## Other resources

It is clear from [w3c documentation](https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-syntax/#Ontology_IRI_and_Version_IRI) how to version entire ontologies/graphs. Each ontology must have a versionIRI, and they may have an ontologyIRI.  It is not clear if there is a non-external (eg not a html solution) inside the rdf file itself to make sure that both the versionIRI (eg example.org/myontology/v04/MyClass123) and the unversioned ontologyIRI (eg. example.org/myontology/**v03**/MyClass123)

In dereferencing, ontologies like FIBO ([example html](https://spec.edmcouncil.org/fibo/ontology/master/2023Q2/BE/GovernmentEntities/NorthAmericanJurisdiction/USGovernmentEntitiesAndJurisdictions/StateOfGeorgiaGovernment) creates a dereferencable version-specific URL (.../ontology/master/2023Q2/BE/... in the version above) for past versions, but I have not been able to find old versions of FIBO to test if the versioned IRI for a particular resource still works in a sparql query.

Comment: there is no such feature in the SPARQL standard that would redirect from one URI to another, i.e. from the versioned URI of the latest ontology revision to the standard URI. SPARQL is just doing pattern matching and there is also no relation to OWL itself as SPARQL is the de-facto query language for RDF and not OWL.

Comment: What you would need are explicit triples in your dataset that map from `/v04/MyClass123` to `/MyClass123` and then you would have to use this triple pattern also in the SPARQL query - which is something that you don't want I guess. The only other option would be to setup some kind of inference engine, which does cover  `owl:sameAs` resp. `owl:equivalentClass` reasoning

Comment: Indeed, also in that case you'll need the semantic equality triples/axioms in your data.

Comment: The FIBO ontology is versioned in Git, you can access older version on Github: https://github.com/edmcouncil/fibo/tree/master/BE - I'm not sure if the old versions are published anywhere else, but you could at least get old version from the Github tags: https://github.com/edmcouncil/fibo/releases